# How to implement persisted sorted list which is often updated and you need maintain the order

Tags: nosql, rdbms, sortedlist, sortedset

I need to display members of community which are sorted by last visit. There are millions of communities each of wich can have millions of members. The list should be scrollable. Because of sorting by last visit time the order is updated very often.

In RDBMS this functionality could be simply done by ordinary B-tree index. But how can I do it with NoSQL approach?

My current thoughts are:

Standart NoSQL scrollable list approach which uses buckets of fixed length that are chained doesn't help much because of requirements of reordering.

[Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) keeps values ordered by column name. So theoretically I could use last visit time as column key but for each update I would need to delete existing column and insert new one which doesn't sound very effectively.

[Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) is not NoSQL storage but also an option because it creates sorted index. But I'm not sure how it is scalable for massive updates.

[Redis Sorted Sets](http://redis.io/topics/data-types) sounds really promising but I haven't had experience with it.

What other options do I have?

Comment: Just found one more option: https://code.google.com/p/leveldb/. Looks like a good fit.

Comment: Redis is in-memory option mostly. It can't store more than it can keep in memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep the last modification date in the object you could sort at query time in many NoSQL db's:

MongoDB (see [docs on indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/)):

```
db.collection.find({ ... spec ... }).sort({ key: 1 })
db.collection.ensureIndex( { "username" : 1, "timestamp" : -1 } )
```

[Elastic search has sorting in queries](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/sort/) too:

```
{
  "sort" : [
      { "date" : {"order" : "asc"} }
  ],
  "query" : {
      ...
  }
}
```

Some storages like CouchDB seem to lack built-in sorting feature altogether so it pays off to have a look at a particular solution before investing in it.